# How to parse xml using JavaScript and identify elements based on attributes

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, xml2js

I am using `xml2js` to convert an `xml` file into a javascript object. I need to identify attributes within element tags in the `xml` file and manipulate the matching element(s).

For example, I have some a `property` element in `test.xml`:

```xml
...
<property name="TemporaryPort" type="input" required="true" order="0">
  <object>endpoint</object>
</property>
<property name="TemporaryPort" type="input" required="false" order="1">
  <object>endpoint</object>
</property>
<property name="TemporaryPort" type="output" required="false" order="2">
  <object>endpoint</object>
</property>
...
```

In my `parse.js` file that is parsing this `xml` file, I would like to identify elements based on their attributes:

```js
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const xml = fs.readFileSync("test.xml");

let output = "";
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
parser.parseString(xml, function(err,result){
  // I would like to find all elements where:
  // required is set to "true", 
  // name is set to "TemporaryPort", and 
  // type is set to "input"
  output="";
  console.log(output);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight change to your .xml file, as I can't see the whole thing, but I assume it's enclosed in a parent wrapper, which I've called `props`.

```
<props>
    <property name="TemporaryPort" type="input" required="true" order="0">
    <object>endpoint</object>
    </property>
    <property name="TemporaryPort" type="input" required="false" order="1">
    <object>endpoint</object>
    </property>
    <property name="TemporaryPort" type="output" required="false" order="2">
    <object>endpoint</object>
    </property>
</props>
```

I've also...

1. Imported `fs`
2. Changed `output` to an array, as your function parses the xml as an array of objects
3. Looped through `result` (the array of objects), `props` (my made up parent wrapper) and `property` the children from the XML file in your example.
4. The loop checks for your required conditions and pushes the object to the `output` array, which it logs at the end.

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const fs = require('fs');

const xml = fs.readFileSync("test.xml");

const output = []
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

parser.parseString(xml, function(err,result){
  result.props.property.forEach(prop => {
    prop['$'].required == 'true' &&
    prop['$'].name == 'TemporaryPort' &&
    prop['$'].type == 'input' &&
    output.push(prop)
  })
  console.log(output)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) ?

sample code:

```js
const
  DomParser = new DOMParser()
, XMLtext = `
  <data_xml>
    <property name="TemporaryPort" type="input" required="true" order="0">
      <object>endpoint 1</object>
    </property>
    <property name="TemporaryPort" type="input" required="false" order="1">
      <object>endpoint 2</object>
    </property>
    <property name="TemporaryPort" type="output" required="false" order="2">
      <object>endpoint 3</object>
    </property>
  </data_xml>`
  ;
let XMLparsed = DomParser.parseFromString( XMLtext, 'application/xml')
  ;


  //  find all elements where:
// required is set to "true", 
// name is set to "TemporaryPort", and 
// type is set to "input"  
 
for (let nod of XMLparsed.querySelectorAll('data_xml property[name="TemporaryPort"][type="input"][required="true"]') )
  {
  for(let subChild of nod.children)
    {
    console.log( '---subChild name:', subChild.nodeName )  
    console.log( '----------content ->', subChild.textContent )  
    } 
  }
console.log('\n\n\n')

// otherwise:

for (let nod of XMLparsed.querySelector('data_xml').children )
  {
  console.log( 'nodeName =', nod.nodeName)
  for(let attr of nod.attributes)
    {
    console.log('---> attribute: name=', attr.name, ',  value=', attr.value)
    }
  for(let subChild of nod.children)
    {
      console.log( '---subChild name:', subChild.nodeName )  
      console.log( '----------content ->', subChild.textContent )  
    }  
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0; }
```